# XMPP and Android An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

Here is my `Mytask` code and when I debug it will give me an error:

```
06-12 16:08:22.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4063): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-12 16:08:22.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4063): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-12 16:08:22.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4063): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-12 16:08:22.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4063): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-12 16:08:22.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4063): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)

protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
     {  
    String host = "web.vlivetech.com";                                  //getText(R.id.host);
    String port =  "5222";                                             //getText(R.id.port);
    String service = "web.vlivetech.com";                             //getText(R.id.service);
    String username =  "has12345";                                   //getText(R.id.userid);
    String password =   "123";                                      //getText(R.id.password);

    // Create a connection
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
            MainActivity.setConnection(null);
        }
        try {
            connection.login(username, password);
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

            // Set the status to available
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            MainActivity.setConnection(connection);
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
            MainActivity.setConnection(null);
        }

      return null;
    }
```

Comment: Post more code & log information if possible.

Comment: 06-12 16:08:22.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4063): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-12 16:08:22.032: E/AndroidRuntime(4063): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()